Add a Checklist Checkbox via Script to a Collapsible Header in Google Doc
I have a current script in Google Docs that adds a header with collapsible list beneath it (on a pageless setup) underneath a specific section of the document.
I am looking to include a Checklist Menu checkbox (that strikes through line when checked) with the header line.

I was able to find ways to create a full list of checkboxes, but haven't been able to identify a way to only make the first line a checkbox (while retaining the existing formatting).
Here's the script I have so far:
function insertText() {
  var header = "Enter_Item_Title_Here"
  var bulletOneHeader = "Agenda Item Owner(s): ___________"
  var bulletTwoHeader = "Discussant: ___________"
  var bulletThreeHeader = "Discussion Date: ___________"
  var bulletFourHeader = "External follow up: ___________"
  var bulletFiveHeader = "Notes: ___________"
  var bulletSixHeader = "Action Items: ___________"
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getActiveTab().asDocumentTab().getBody();
  var pr = cursor.findText("New Items:").getElement().getParent();
  var i = cursor.getChildIndex(pr) + 1;
  cursor.insertParagraph(i, header).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3);
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 1, bulletOneHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 2, bulletTwoHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 3, bulletThreeHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 4, bulletFourHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 5, bulletFiveHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
  cursor.insertListItem(i + 6, bulletSixHeader).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes({ [DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]: true });
}

Here's an example google doc that includes the script I have so far.

Unavailable Feature
What you're trying to achieve is not currently implemented yet in DocumentApp. It was also asked by a community member from another forum last March 2023. And someone filed this as a featured request, but the requester is not active, which is the reason why the featured request was closed.
I would encourage you to send this as a new feature request by going to this link. The feedback submitted there will go directly to the development team, and the more people who request a feature like this, the more likely it will be implemented.

I was able to make this example work, but it is a full list: https://medium.com/google-cloud/inserting-paragraphs-with-checkboxes-in-google-documents-using-google-apps-script-ed16479fbfe1
Is the difference here that it is a full checkbox list, vs what I am looking for?

I was able to find ways to create a full list of checkboxes, but haven't been able to identify a way to only make the first line a checkbox (while retaining the existing formatting)  - What you are looking for is to retain the formatting and just want the first line to be a check box. The article that you have sent is different from what you want to achieve because it's only applicable if you want it to be a full list.
